# El modal de Bootstrap no me genera el modal y cuando lo genera no me permite cerrarlo

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Hice un modal con Bootstrap, recibe la información, sin embargo al picar en el botón, no me permite visualizarla, puede ser por el atributo class, sin embargo, ninguna configuración me lo soluciona. En algunas ocasiones con la configuración "modal fade", muestra el modal y no la información, pero no se deja cerrar tampoco.

Les dejo el código, ya que la idea es implementar el modal para visualizar la información de una tabla, para crear algo similar a unos "términos y condiciones". Las columnas no están bien nombradas, pero es lo de menos, solo quiero saber cómo podría realizar esa parte.

```
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
<!-- wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1>LISTA DE CLIENTES</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= base_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Nombre</th>
                                            <th>Nit</th>
                                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                                            <th>Direción</th>
                                            <th>Autorizó</th>
                                            <th>Aclaraciones de entrega</th>
                                            <th>Aclaraciones de entrega</th>
                                            <th>Aclaraciones de entrega</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                        if (!empty($cliente)) {
                                            foreach ($cliente->result() as $regis) {
                                        ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><?= $regis->NombreCliente;  ?></td>
                                                    <td><?= $regis->NitCliente;  ?> </td>
                                                    <td><?= $regis->TelefonoCliente;  ?></td>
                                                    <td><?= $regis->DirecCliente;  ?></td>
                                                    <td><?= $regis->PAutorizada;  ?></td>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <textarea style="display:none" id="textarea<?= $regis->IDCliente; ?>" cols="30" rows="10"><?= $regis->Aclaraciones ?></textarea>
                                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" onclick='openModal("textarea<?= $regis->IDCliente; ?>")'>Ver</button>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="<?= base_url() ?>Cliente/verEdicion/<?= $regis->IDCliente; ?>"><i class=""></i> Editar</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="" onclick="elim(<?= $regis->IDCliente; ?>)" role="button">Eliminar</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                        <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            <div id="modalprueba" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal dialog" role="document" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- Page specific script -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#example1").DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "buttons": ["excel", "print", "colvis"]
        }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
    });
</script>
<!-- Importar js Cliente -->
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>Js/js_Cliente.js"></script>
```

Comment: No olvides mencionar qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando. Puedes colocarlo además en las etiquetas.

Comment: Por cierto, 1. ¿y la función openModal? No olvides colocar un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_). 2. No está demás recordar que [no se recomienda utilizar los manejadores de eventos _inline_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Comment: Hola, es boostrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaría algunos atributos al botón que abre el modal.

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalprueba"
```

Quedando tu botón terminado, se ve así:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalprueba" onclick='openModal("textarea<?= $regis->IDCliente; ?>")'>Ver</button>
```

Esto abriría el modal independientemente de la carga de datos.

Comment: Había que hacer algunas otras modificaciones, sin embargo, el cierre del modal funcionó gracias al atributo data-toggle="modal". Muchas gracias!!